# Google Cloud Storage Domain lock

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Hello l will like to set Google Cloud Storage to work only in some domain. example l store videos in the google cloud but l don't want other website to use then.
also l try to use the public but they still use the url

Comment: Have you trie anything yet? It's not possible to help you unless we know what all you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a built-in feature of GCS. However, you could implement it by making the videos private but having an app engine app that checked the referer of incoming requests and either failed or returned a signed URL for accessing the video.

Comment: But how to do that. l don't have experience with google cloud store